# Apache Spark RDD Transpose

Tags: apache-spark, transpose

I am doing ETL on securities market data in order to generate a Self Organizing Map.  I'd like to transpose the row data:

AAME, 20030101, 1.63, 1.63, 1.63, 1.63, 0 
AAON, 20030101, 5.4635, 5.4635, 5.4635, 5.4635, 0 
AAPL, 20030101, 7.165, 7.165, 7.165, 7.165, 0 
ABAX, 20030101, 3.96, 3.96, 3.96, 3.96, 0
...
ZUMZ, 20131104, 29.55, 29.79, 29.18, 29.46, 218100

into column data:

AAME  1.63, 1.65, ...
AAON  5.4635, 5.3

Should I try to use ReduceByKey(extend) or ReduceByKey(append) should I try a BlockMatrix?

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html#blockmatrix

E.g. -

```
val matA: BlockMatrix = coordMat.toBlockMatrix().cache()

// Validate whether the BlockMatrix is set up properly. Throws an Exception when it is not valid.
// Nothing happens if it is valid.
matA.validate()

// Calculate A^T A.
val ata = matA.transpose.multiply(matA)
```